# Terminology when factoring difference of squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, factoring

So, as we all know,

$$(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$$

I remember learning a special piece of vocabulary in high school related to this.

$(a-b)$ is the _____ of $(a+b)$.

$(a+b)$ is the _____ of $(a-b)$.

For any binomial, you can form its ______ by reversing the sign of its second term.

Can you guys help me fill in the blank?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the term "conjugate" which confusingly has many varied uses depending on context.  See [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(algebra)) on wikipedia.

Comment: I'm definitely leaning toward "conjugate"

Comment: Yes! It is definitely "conjugate". Thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question doesn't languish in the "Unanswered" queue for ages?